# kunalvarma05 dropbox-php-sdk

Tags: php, dropbox-api, dropbox-php

i use this unofficial api to manage file on dropbox , i want show in my website the list of file and with this list manage them with the metod delete() .

To return the list of file i use the :

```
include('../dropbox-2-k/vendor/autoload.php');

use Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp;
use Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox;

$app = new DropboxApp("xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");


//Configure Dropbox service
$dropbox = new Dropbox($app);

$listFolderContents = $dropbox->listFolder("/");

//Fetch Items (Returns an instance of ModelCollection)
 $items = $listFolderContents->getItems();

//All Items
$files=$items->toArray();
```

this return an array formed by FileMetadata Object as this :

```
Kunnu\Dropbox\Models\FileMetadata Object ( [id:protected] => id:3QPTxoe-gHAAAAAAAAAAAg [name:protected] => cambio_nome.txt [rev:protected] => 14c8c2758 [size:protected] => 40 [path_lower:protected] => /cambio_nome.txt [media_info:protected] => [sharing_info:protected] => [path_display:protected] => /cambio_nome.txt [client_modified:protected] => 2016-08-13T17:09:42Z [server_modified:protected] => 2016-08-13T17:09:42Z [has_explicit_shared_members:protected] => [data:protected] => Array ( [.tag] => file [name] => cambio_nome.txt [path_lower] => /cambio_nome.txt [path_display] => /cambio_nome.txt [id] => id:3QPTxoe-gHAAAAAAAAAAAg [client_modified] => 2016-08-13T17:09:42Z [server_modified] => 2016-08-13T17:09:42Z [rev] => 14c8c2758 [size] => 40 ) ) Kunnu\Dropbox\Models\FileMetadata Object ( [id:protected] => id:3QPTxoe-gHAAAAAAAAAAAw [name:protected] => 20150805_181544.jpg [rev:protected] => 24c8c2758 [size:protected] => 1735369 [path_lower:protected] => /20150805_181544.jpg [media_info:protected] => [sharing_info:protected] => [path_display:protected] => /20150805_181544.jpg [client_modified:protected] => 2016-08-21T07:34:23Z [server_modified:protected] => 2016-08-21T07:34:23Z [has_explicit_shared_members:protected] => [data:protected] => Array ( [.tag] => file [name] => 20150805_181544.jpg [path_lower] => /20150805_181544.jpg [path_display] => /20150805_181544.jpg [id] => id:3QPTxoe-gHAAAAAAAAAAAw [client_modified] => 2016-08-21T07:34:23Z [server_modified] => 2016-08-21T07:34:23Z [rev] => 24c8c2758 [size] => 1735369 ) )
```

i must extract the name ([name:protected]).

How i can do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering with this library too, as it is not able to download files. I don't know why.

Anyway, to solve your problem, you could use $item->name as follows:

```
$items = $listFolderContents->getItems();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getData()['.tag'] == 'folder') {
        // this is a folder
        echo $item->name;
    }

    if ($item->getData()['.tag'] == 'file') {
        // this is a file
        echo $item->name;
    }
}
```